# Como fazer uma pesquisa no google com vba?

Tags: html, vba

Estou com dificuldade para montar uma programação em VBA que faça uma pesquisa no google.
Não consigo entender a parte do HTML.

A ideia é identificar o internet explorer aberto, ir para a página do google e buscar a palavra "teste" na pesquisa.

Segue código:

```
Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim objShell As Object
Dim objWindow As Object
Dim objItem As Object
Dim objCollection As Object

Sub teste()

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objWindow = objShell.Windows()
For Each objItem In objWindow
    If LCase(objItem.FullName Like "*Internet Explorer*") Then
        Set ie = objItem
    End If
Next objItem

ie.navigate ("https://www.google.com.br/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=-s-bVf3ZBcf5gASo1oHAAw&gws_rd=ssl")

Do While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> 4
DoEvents
Loop '** Wait til page loaded

Set objCollection = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

i = 0



Do While i < objCollection.all.Length
    If objCollection.all(i).ID = "q" Then
        objCollection.all(i).Value = "teste"
        Exit Do
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop


End Sub
```

Comment: Acho que acessar o internet explorer assim é arriscado e ineficiente. Além disso, acessar o conteúdo da página para realizar a buscar parece complicado demais, inutilmente. Porque não usar o Shell para abrir o endereço da pesquiza `https://www.google.com.br/search?q={busca}`? O windows vai abrir, automaticamente, a janela do navegador padrão, e uma aba nova se o navegador estiver aberto.

Comment: O que eu queria era entender a lógica do HTML, para usar em outros sites depois.

Comment: Minto, acho que fazer isso vai abrir o windows explorer, independente de qual é o navegador padrão. Ainda assim recomendo essa linha.

Comment: O que quer dizer com lógica do html? Você quer analizar a html da página do google?

Comment: Sim, não estou conseguindo fazer a busca dos campos pelo html.
Seria a mesma lógica para preencher formulários online, analisar o HTML para identificar o id do campo e usar o VBA para preenchê-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui entender o problema.

segue solução que encontrei:

```
Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim objShell As Object
Dim objWindow As Object
Dim objItem As Object
Dim objCollection As Object

Sub teste()

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objWindow = objShell.Windows()
For Each objItem In objWindow
    If LCase(objItem.FullName Like "*Internet Explorer*") Then
        Set ie = objItem
    End If
Next objItem

ie.navigate ("https://www.google.com.br/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=-s-bVf3ZBcf5gASo1oHAAw&gws_rd=ssl")

Do While ie.Busy Or ie.READYSTATE <> 4
DoEvents
Loop '** Wait til page loaded

Set objCollection = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

i = 0



Do While i < objCollection.Length
    If objCollection(i).Name = "q" Then
        objCollection(i).Value = "teste"
        Exit Do
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Na página do google, o `ID` não é "q".

O elemento `input` onde se digita a busca tem atributo `name="q"`.

Novamente, acho que essa forma de lançar a busca no google é contra-indicada. Eu executaria um `Shell` com o endereço do googgle, inserindo a texto pesquizado.